# Lilypond function; add a rhythm to a note

Tags: function, lilypond

How can you write a Lilypond function that takes in a note and outputs a note with a rhythm? say:
input: c'
output: c'8 c'16 c'

Answer (score 5):

In the [LilyPond documentation](http://www.lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/snippets-big-page.html#pitches-creating-a-sequence-of-notes-on-various-pitches) you can find this example:

```
rhythm =
#(define-music-function (parser location p) (ly:pitch?)
   "Make the rhythm in Mars (the Planets) at the given pitch"
  #{ \tuplet 3/2 { $p 8 $p $p } $p 4 $p $p 8 $p $p 4 #})

\new Staff {
  \time 5/4
  \rhythm c'
  \rhythm c''
  \rhythm g
}
```

[image]

Hopefully that can be adapted to do what you want! Replace the Mars rhythm with your own. And please note that a space is needed between the variable `$p` and the durations.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, it only works on the developmental version of LilyPond.

Comment: Sorry about that! I have edited the example with the example from 2.18 instead. But actually the principle is the same, you write in your rhythm and write `$p` where the real pitch should go.

Comment: How would you do the same thing but with a chord?